# How store a json document in an elasticsearch index using the Apache Pulsar connector?

Tags: elasticsearch, connector, apache-pulsar

I want to store JSON schema as {"name": "Jane", "age": 25, ...} in Elasticsearch using Apache Pulsar connector. I tried using this https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/io-elasticsearch-sink/#configuration, but I can only store JSON with the structure {string: number}.
Somebody could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push your data in using a schema.

It is similar to what I did with SOLR.

https://github.com/tspannhw/FLIp-Solr

see the java code.   make sure you have a schema to get it to land correct

https://vimeo.com/628573854

https://www.slideshare.net/bunkertor/real-time-cloud-native-open-source-streaming-of-any-data-to-apache-solr

That should work